# use jquery string in form GET method

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to replace characters using jquery and I want to pass it into a form action get method. Right now I am getting the value of a text field and sending it to the get method. I want to check and replace the a character in the string and then pass it afterwards.. How do I do that?

my code:

```
    <li>
        <form action="Citizen/CitizenSearch" method="get">
            <input class="cpr-search" type="text" name="cpr" />
            <input class="cpr-search" name="submit" type="hidden" value="Søg" />
        </form>
    </li>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Søg').keypress(function (e) {
        var cpr = $('#cpr').val();
        if (cpr.indexOf("-") >= 0) {
            cpr = cpr.replace("-", "");
        }
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $(this).blur();
            $('#submit').focus().click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: so you want to redirect to a URL consisting of the value of input in `cpr-search` ?

Comment: it does redirect.. But if the search contains a symbol live '-' then i want to replace that symbol with empty space and send it instead of the old text. So `newText = oldText.replace("-", "");` and use newText in `<input class="cpr-search" type="text" name="newText" />`

Comment: if you want only alphanumeric characters to be allowed you can regex like `cpr.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/gi, '');`

Comment: @sagarpatro but how do i pass the new value istead of the actual text from textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can access the text fields using the `name` attribute, i will use them as ids. so here is the script. give it a try.

```
 <li>
        <form action="Citizen/CitizenSearch" method="get">
            <input class="cpr-search" type="text" id="cpr" />
            <input class="cpr-search" name="submit" type="hidden" id="Søg" />
        </form>
    </li>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Søg').keypress(function (e) {
        var cpr = $('#cpr').val();
        cpr= cpr.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/gi, '');
//This replace here will replace everything except alphanumeric values. gi is for global.
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $(location).attr('href', '/your_path?q=' + cpr);
//This statement will redirect you to your required location with the value of the text field that you intended.
//q is a get variable so that you can use it in next page.
        }
    });
</script>
```